# Syntax for <Ast.expr> in OCaml parsing

Tags: ocaml

I have an ocaml Abstract Syntax Tree file, called `astDual.ml`, and associated `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll` files.

In `parser.mly`, typically we write:

```
%start <Ast.expr> prog
```

after declaring tokens and associativity.

But since my file is not `ast.ml`, but instead `astDual.ml`, should I change this to

```
%start <AstDual.expr> prog
```

?

Comment: Do you have a type named `expr` in your `AstDual` module?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield yes

Comment: Then I'd say, yes, you should make this change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, files in OCaml correspond to modules that have the same name but with the first letter capitalized. See the corresponding section in the [manual](https://ocaml.org/manual/moduleexamples.html#s:separate-compilation) for more information.